# Recovering a deleted Firebird database file?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, ntfs, data-recovery

I've got a client running a radio server which essentially uses Firebird as the database. (Databases are stored in files ending in `*.fdb` anywhere on the filesystem, think SQLite) I had to reinstall the radio server software to switch it to use MySQL, and I think it basically wiped the Firebird database. Only afterwards did I realize how much important information was in the database. Major fail.

I was wondering if I could employ some elite hackery to try and recover the database file. The server is running (*gasp*) Vista and NTFS. Is there something I can do here?

Answer (score 2):

You reinstalled the operating system and are surprised that it over-wrote the database files? Methinks you're a bit out of your depth here.

While there's a very small chance that some of the database files could be recovered, it's going to take some work, most likely by a professional data recovery outfit ala Kroll Ontrack.

Honestly your best bet is to restore from backup and be done with it. That's going to be your quickest path back to a functional system

Comment: Nope, sorry, I meant the "radio server software," I just updated it. I didn't format the drive at all, the OS is intact, I just had to reinstall the server software, not the operating system.

Comment: Well if you've manually verified that the *.fdb files are gone, you can try using one of the many NTFS file recovery suites out there. The issue you're probably going to run into though is that when files are restored by these packages, they are unable to recover the filename, so it just picks a sequential filename for each file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. If you have any recommended software in particular, it'd be most appreciated.

Comment: I can't recommend any specific package, though a quick google will no doubt return dozens of options. Why don't you just recover from backup? That's really going to be the quickest thing for you to do.

Comment: Ah, if only they would have made backups... umm, lesson learned, anyone?

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but this is on you. As the sysadmin, it was your responsibility to ensure your ability to revert the change before you took any action. I suspect both you and your client have learned your lessons here, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly the sysadmin, I was only hired as a developer, then assigned the migration task. Lesson learned.

Comment: @TK, like so many others, our jobs always look easier until you have to do it yourself. ;)

Comment: In my own defense, I did indeed fail, but only by assuming that Firebird was a standalone database server and not a SQLite-ish/portable/file-based database. Like I said, client tells me to migrate to MySQL, the radio server company tells me to reinstall, I do so, and then realize the db is gone. In any case, backups will be part of the program now.